# Cancelling Schengen Student Visa Application

Tags: schengen, study, cancellations, portugal

I have applied for a student visa at the Portugal embassy in my home country and my visa has been granted. The embassy has called me to buy a ticket and present it to the embassy so that they can stick it to my passport. If I don't want to go to Portugal anymore (for personal reasons), can I ask them to cancel the granted visa and collect my passport? Does this cause any problem for my future Schengen visa or student visa applications?? Or would it be better for me to travel to Portugal and like stay there for 2 weeks and then come back?

Comment: Why did they ask you to purchase the ticket before getting the visa affixed in your passport? Typically all they want is a printout of a booking without the ticket being actually purchased. Was there something during the visa interview which made them somewhat suspicious you would not be traveling?

Comment: @SheikPaul: It's the routine in here. When the visa is ready, you have to provide them with confirmed flight tickets.

Comment: Is it really necessary to close this as off-topic because it's about long-term travel? The question is about cancelling a visa. Unless the answer is different for a multi-year study visa than for a short-term visit visa, why not just answer the question here?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I tagged long stay visa because I'm talking about cancelling a long stay visa before using it. I just wanna know if that causes any problem or not (like banning from applying for another one in the future, bad visa application record, etc)

Comment: @Arrrr Your tags are fine and I think your question is fine. But people here seem to automatically vote to close any question about long-term visas as being off-topic.

Comment: @pnuts See my previous comment. In cases like this, where question applies to all visas, why close just because the visa mentioned happens to be a long-term one? If the question had just said "visa" instead of "student visa", the answers would be the same and nobody would vote to close. So is the question really off-topic? I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I don't want to go to Portugal anymore (for personal reasons), can I ask them to cancel the granted visa and collect my passport?

YES. You are a free human being and are allowed to change your mind. Your passport is your (and your country's) property, not the Portuguese embassy's.

> Does this cause any problem for my future Schengen visa or student visa applications?

In itself should not if there is no suspicion of fraud on their part. People are issued visas all the time and don't travel without any detrimental infect on them.

> Or would it be better for me to travel to Portugal and like stay there for 2 weeks and then come back?

Would not make sense in general, and particular in this case where you have a students visa. Actually I think that could be viewed more negatively. A student visa is not meant for tourism.

Comment: +1 I don't know specifically about Portugal, but in general you are supposed to use a visa to enter a country only when traveling for the purpose you stated when applying for the visa.

Comment: Please if possible answer this question I have as it is rather urgent, I have talked to a lawyer today and I have been told that if I ask to cancel my visa, they will most probably reject all my future applications. To what extent is this true and what if I apply through another embassy next time?

Comment: The lawyer does not know what he is talking about. Unless you lied on your student visa application. Did you tell some lies on the student visa application? If no, you have nothing to worry about. If yes, then you could be in trouble and subsequent applications denied for fraud. What good reason do you have for not wanting the students visa anymore?

Comment: I did not lie. I did want to go to Portugal but I just changed my mind. The actual reason is that instead of going there I wanna start a business somewhere else and not interested in doing my master degree anymore.